# Google Stackdriver - How can I show the logs of multiple containers in one view?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am currently using Google Stackdriver (the new layout!) to investigate my logging. In my case there are three services communicating between each other. I'd love to see their communication between each other in the form of my INFO logging in the most convenient way possible.

`FooService > BarService > SnickerService`

### Status Quo

Currently I am only able to see the log of one of either services. So I started to open three browser tabs and having all three mentioned service logs opened. Now I figure out a timestamp/range where the `FooService` started calling `BarService`.
This timerange I apply to the other remaining two services.
That way I have a overview how the process is being distributed among those services.

**This way to do it however is super awkward to setup every time**

This leads me to the question if I can bring the logging of three containers into one Stackdriver view?

In the log query I see this field (example FooService)

```
resource.labels.pod_name="fooservice-bd4c9bf4d-nv4k2"
```

### Questions

- Is there a way to have a `AND` operation here?
- Is there also a way to "search" for pods? At the moment I always have to dive into my Workloads and dig for the pod id (example above: bd4c9bf4d-nv4k2) so I can use it in the query. By doing so I would be way faster just clicking `View Logs` in the Google Cloud Console. So this can't be much of a fast way imho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use 2 operators

- : is the contain operator
- () is a group operator

With : you can search on partial name. Use this `resource.labels.pod_name: "fooservice"` matches all the *fooservice* pod name.

With () you can group values or comparison, like this ("foo" OR "bar")

If you put all together

```
resource.labels.pod_name: ("fooservice" OR "barservice")
```

-> This filter allows you to filter on the pod_name which contains the values "fooservice" OR "barservice"

Comment: Managing the Summary Fields to add `pod_name` helps later to identify the log to a asked pod

Comment: Thanks - yet again I find myself on SO for something easy because googles log queries docs sucks...

Comment: @AdamHughes. Agree and when I discover on SO some GCP Query/Filter ninjas, I take time to understand their logic and query explanation!!